# linq query times out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

my Linq query times out and the results are never retreived..

```
using (var repository = PersistenceService.GetRepository<Organisation>(UserId))
 {
 var organisation = repository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == organisationId);
            if (organisation != null)
            {
                        isCourseApproverRole = organisation.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(con => con.RoleName == "CourseApprover" && 
                                                            con.Individual.Id == individualId) != null;
            }
}
```

When I try doing all this in one query it works fine..
Can some one explain why above query will time out??

Note: organisation.Contacts contain about 18,000 rows for the selected organisation.

Comment: Just look at the generated SQL statements and you'll know.

Comment: open sql profilere then run your project check what type of sql query generated  based on that you can change your sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of massive lazy loading.

The first command...

```
var organisation = repository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == organisationId);
```

... pulls an `Organisation` object into memory. That shouldn't be any problem.

But then you access `organisation.Contacts`. It doesn't matter which LINQ method you apply to this collection, the *whole* collection is pulled into memory by lazy loading. The LINQ filter is applied afterwards.

However, though highly inefficient, this still shouldn't cause a timeout. Fetching 18000 records by an indexed search (I assume) shouldn't take more than 30s (I assume) unless something else is terribly wrong (like low resources, bad network).

The part `con.Individual.Id == individualId` is the culprit. If you would have monitored the executed SQL commands you'd have seen that this causes one query for each `Individual` until the predicate `Id == individualId` is matched. These queries run while the query `organisation.Contacts` is read. No doubt, this causes the timeout.

You could fix this by replacing the predicate by `con.IndividualId == individualId` (i.e. using the foreign key property). But I really don't understand why you don't do this in one query, which works fine, as you say. By the current approach you fetch large amounts of data, while in the end you only need one boolean value!

Comment: thanks,, I managed to get this done in one query, however question was asked to understand what was the culprit in the query..
Also your commnet about using the foreign key property in the contact table is useful and this in my case was the culprit.. thanks for identifying.